# Regex condensing newlines not translating to PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to take markdown (generated from HTML) and strip out extra newlines that were only in the HTML for formatting purposes.  I have a working example of the regex on https://regex101.com/r/dEhyN3/1 but when I convert it to PHP it's not working and I'm struggling to understand why.

```
public function squashEmptyLineBreaks(string $markdown) : string
{
    return preg_replace('/\n{2,}/', '\n\n', $markdown);
}
```

Test:

```
    /** @test */
    public function verifySquashEmptyLineBreaks()
    {
        $original = <<<EOF
**Language**

 - Added four languages: Italian, Portuguese (Brazil), Spanish (Mexico) and Chinese (Traditional)





**Bug fixes**


 - Fixed camera jittering for passenger sitting on the back of a motorcycle with sidecar
EOF;
        $expected = <<<EOF
**Language**

 - Added four languages: Italian, Portuguese (Brazil), Spanish (Mexico) and Chinese (Traditional)

**Bug fixes**

 - Fixed camera jittering for passenger sitting on the back of a motorcycle with sidecar
EOF;

        $this->assertEquals($expected, $this->parsesMarkdown->headersNeverAtEndOfLine($original));
    }
```

This test continues to fail and the output is unmodified.  **Am I crazy or am I overlooking something?**

Comment: '\n\n' is not a double line break. cf. http://php.net/string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove excessive line returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728640/remove-excessive-line-returns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware, in single quoted strings, sequences such as `\n` are not processed. Use double-quoted strings instead.

```
public function squashEmptyLineBreaks(string $markdown) : string
{
    return preg_replace("/\n{2,}/", "\n\n", $markdown);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you were right, there was an issue with my test assertion.

Comment: Looks like this works for some, but not for others given some of the newlines have spaces/tabs that existed in HTML.  Still hunting down a solution for that...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47461895/regex-match-empty-lines answered my next question