# Regex match empty lines

Tags: regex

Currently I have a regex that will take a given set of newlines and condense them.  A challenge I need to solve for is to [modify this regex](https://regex101.com/r/dEhyN3/2) (`\n{2,}`) so that it still will ignore spaces and tabs when searching for multiple newline characters.

https://regex101.com/r/dEhyN3/2 shows a good working example of what I'm referring to.  There's a line that only contains a space which leads to too many new lines in the end result.

Comment: Could you please explain the problem and add the regex fiddle into the question? My phone browser crashes when opening regex101.

Comment: [\n\s*\n](https://regex101.com/r/9LHLci/1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Brief

This answer ensures whitespace at the start of a line is kept (if it contains something other than a whitespace character).

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/PsvDZP/1)

```
(?:\h*\n){2,}
```

**Note**: Some regex engines don't allow `\h`, so this will have to be replaced with `[\t\p{Zs}]`, and if Unicode character classes are not supported, a simple list of each character such as `[\t ]` or `[^\S\n]`.

**Other methods:**

```
(?:\n(?:[^\S\n]*(?=\n))?){2,}
(?:\n(?:\s*(?=\n))?){2,}
\h*\n(?:\h*\n)+
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
**Language**

 - Added four languages: Italian, Portuguese (Brazil), Spanish (Mexico) and Chinese (Traditional)





**Bug fixes**


 - Fixed camera jittering for passenger sitting on the back of a motorcycle with sidecar
 - Fixed camera jittering for passenger sitting on the back of a motorcycle with sidecar
```

#### Output

```
**Language**

 - Added four languages: Italian, Portuguese (Brazil), Spanish (Mexico) and Chinese (Traditional)

**Bug fixes**

 - Fixed camera jittering for passenger sitting on the back of a motorcycle with sidecar
 - Fixed camera jittering for passenger sitting on the back of a motorcycle with sidecar
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?:\h*\n){2,}` Match any number of horizontal whitespace character followed by a line-feed, two or more times

#### Other methods

Just to explain at least one of the other methods (and keep my original answer)

- `(?:\n(?:[^\S\n]*(?=\n))?){2,}` Matches the following two or more times

  - `\n` Match a line-feed character
  - `(?:[^\S\n]*(?=\n))?` Match the following zero or one time

    - `[^\S\n]*` Match any whitespace character except `\n` any number of times
    - `(?=\n)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is a line-feed `\n`

Comment: In Java and PHP, [`\R`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lineending) would be better than `\n`, since that matches both Windows and Linux style line breaks.

Comment: @Andreas thanks, didn't know that one. What about `\v` instead (in PCRE for example)?

Comment: [`\v`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef) is "A vertical whitespace character: `[\n\x0B\f\r\x85\u2028\u2029]`", while `\R` is "Any Unicode linebreak sequence, is equivalent to `\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]`". Basically, `\R` is `\r\n|\v`, i.e. same as `\v` but also matching the CRLF **pair** of Windows.

Comment: @Andreas awesome thanks! That gives me good information going forward :)

Answer (score 2):

This method is shorter than the top answer:

```
(\h*\n){2,}
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dEhyN3/12)

Comment: This is only shorter due to removing `?:` from my answer, which may cause loss in performance